# Isolating class attribute from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

HTML:

```
<body class="" data-is-article="story" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1094.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
```

How would I extract "story" as a string variable from "data-is-article" using beautiful soup?

I have tried:

```
type = soup.find('body', class_="data-is-article")
```

But get a `None` response

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Avoid using `python` reserved terms ([`keywords`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)), this could have unwanted effects on the results of your code.*

---

`data-is-article` is not a class, it is an attribute - so simply access the attribute value of element via [`.get('ATTRIBUT NAME')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
soup.body.get('data-is-article')
```

or based on your selection:

```
soup.find('body', {'data-is-article':True}).get('data-is-article')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<body class="" data-is-article="story" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1094.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.body.get('data-is-article')
```