# python web crawling data-score

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

suppose below is the source page

```
<span class="xxx" data-tip="a" title="a" **data-score="100"** currentitem="false" style="color: rgb(251, 195, 8); padding-top: 0px;"><i class="i-thumb-up"></i></span>
```

i want to get the value of data-score from the page which is 100.

the below code i tried which is not working

```
import requests
response = requests.get(
"https:website")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())  

result = soup.find_all("data-score")

for i in result :
    print (i)
```

no data return

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75232927/14460824